# network simulation/emulation on a windows machine?

Tags: windows, networking, simulation, virtualbox, emulation

I am using a laptop with Win7 x64. I would like to simulate packet loss, latency, etc. without the need of a second machine.

I came across [WAN Connection Emulator](http://www.softperfect.com/products/connectionemulator/) and [Network Simulator](http://www.akmalabs.com/netsim.php) but both tools don't work for me. For the first one I get a network driver initializing error and the second one doesn't install at all.

Now I've tried WANem with VirtualBox but I'm not sure how I can route the traffic through the VM. 
Since the laptop has one NIC and one WiFi adapter should'n it be somehow possible to use one interface (eg. Ethernet) for the VM and route the other one (e.g. WiFi) through it?

Maybe someone know if and how I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance!
Regards

Answer (score 0):

I would simulate everything on virtual machines only. You can build IMHO 32 NICs for each machine and connect if as you like in logical or physical networks.

I don't know what you want to achieve, but I assisted in building a setup for simulating packet loss for an auto-adaptive multimedia codec. We build multiple linux machines and set up a bridge machine, which acts like a man-in-the-middle "attacker" randomly dropping packets. It works fine and was complete virtualized (also very cool for demos).

Comment: This sounds great! Thank you! 
I doubt though that this would work at my workplace since every single MAC address needs to be released by the IT department. 
I had s similar use case like you in mind. Testing the behaviour of various video conferencing tools under a certain amount of packet loss. 
I was hoping to be able to achieve this with one machine or max 2.
On Mac OS X this can be easily done with the `ipfw` command.